# HTTP Progressive Streaming from .mp4 link problem in Android 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, video, mp4

http://streaming.sit.kmutt.ac.th/test.mp4

Using above link, I use web browser in android 2.2 open this link, it cannot stream video using video player. But if I use android 2.3.x, it's ok.

Why android 2.2 cannot view mp4 file using video player?